# How to change the name of dictionary in the file when using klepto.archives.file_archive?

Tags: python, klepto

After running the following code, I found that the name of the dictionary in file `memo.py` is `memo`. I want to change the name of the dictionary in that file. Do anyone know how to do it?

```
>>> init = {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>> import klepto
>>> cache = klepto.archives.file_archive('memo', init, serialized=False)
>>> cache        
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>>
>>> # dump dictionary to the file 'memo.py'
>>> cache.dump() 
>>> 
>>> # import from 'memo.py'
>>> from memo import memo
>>> print memo
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>> from memo import memo
>>> print memo
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `klepto` author.  I don't believe it's possible, currently.  However, if you do want it as a feature, then feel free to request it (on `klepto`'s GitHub) as an enhancement.